# how to apply a between operation globally for a string

Tags: javascript, regex, underscore.string.js, string.js

I have an html string with multiple table tags.

```
   String str = '<table>......</table> <table>....</table>';
```

when I use string.js and the following code.

```
S(str).between('<table>', '</table>').s,
```

I am only getting the 1st table element of the string. I need to get all the table elements (possibly as an array). Is this possible with stringjs?
is it better to use stringjs or a regular expression?

Comment: no..simply as a string

Comment: Are the `<table>` elements nested inside other `<table>` elements? Like `<table>...<table>...</table></table>`

Comment: no..no deep nested tables...structure looks like <table>...</table>  <table>...</table>

Comment: Use regex [`/<table>(.*?)<\/table>/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/nO5qS7/1) and iterate over matches, extract first captured group. Here's [live fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/x9q4ranh/1)

Comment: Yeah, if there are no nested tables, the shortcut is to is a regex like `/<table>([^]*?)<\/table>/gi` / `/<table>([\s\S]*?)<\/table>/gi` / `/<table(?:\s[^>]*)?>([\s\S]*?)<\/table>/gi`, etc., what suits best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you need to split the big string, remove occurrences of `<table>` and `</table>`, and then map through the resulting array. Something like

```
const str = '<table>......</table> <table>....</table>';
const subs = str.split('<table>').map(substring => substring.replace('</table>', ''));
console.log(subs);  // -> ['......', '....']
```

It only works when you have a huge string that represents many `table` siblings, and that's exactly what you asked for.